# How can I rewrite a URL to use a new path for Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite a URL so that following is achieved:

`example.com/old/index.htm` is redirected to `example.com/new/index.htm` ?

I've tried to add the following `RewriteRule` in my server config `vhost` to no avail:

```
<Location /old>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /$1 /new/$1 [R]
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use mod_rewrite directives inside a `<Location>` wrapper. The docs [explicitly warn against this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

However, to simply redirect "old" to "new" you don't necessarily need mod_rewrite. A simple mod_alias `Redirect` directive would suffice. Although a possible exception to this is if you are already using mod_rewrite for other redirects/rewrites.

For example:

```
Redirect 302 /old/ /new/
```

The `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, and everything after the match is copied to the end of the target URL. So, the above will redirect `/old/<anything>` to `/new/<anything>`.

Or with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?old/(.*) /new/$1 [R=302,L]
```

`R` (without an explicit response code) is the same as `R=302`, however, it is often better to be explicit.

Comment: Indeed, I was not paying attention. Using `Redirect` is the most straightforward thing to do in this situation. Thanks for your help and also for the alternative using `RewriteRule`, I still have a lot to learn in that area.

Comment: @wouter205 You're welcome. I've just realised I didn't add any explanation regarding the `Redirect` directive - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect! I only used `Redirect` for HTTPS redirection so I forgot that anything that comes after the match is copied as well. Good reminder :-)

Comment: Yes, this is often overlooked.